# React Native IAP not getting Prices in locale(INR) always getting USD

Tags: iphone, react-native, in-app-purchase

Respected Team,

I am using React Native to develop an application that uses IAP(In-app purchase). I am using **react-native-iap** package for the same. Most of the functionality is working fine especially on the emulator.

The problem started when I started using an actual device for testing.

I created a **Non-Renewing Subscription** on App Store Connect for 89INR. I created this in INR as this application has to be used for INDIA only.

But I am getting .99$ in USD when calling from an actual physical iPhone 7. Although my phone region setting is set for INDIA(locale). Still, I am getting the value in USD.

Now the problem is in the price list I am only showing 89INR but on the actual physical device, I am getting .99 USD due to which my app is also getting rejected on App Store.

Code I used:

```
    IAP.getSubscriptions(['DokoMonthlyPack']).then((res) => {
                    this.setState({ products: res })
                    console.warn("Checking Products", res);
                }).catch(()=> {console.warn("Something went wrong")});
```

The result on Emulator:

```
Checking Products [{"countryCode": "IND", "currency": "INR", "description": "", "discounts": [], "introductoryPrice": "", "introductoryPriceAsAmountIOS": "", "introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriodsIOS": "", "introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS": "", "introductoryPriceSubscriptionPeriodIOS": "", "localizedPrice": "₹ 89.00", "price": "89", "productId": "DokoMonthlyPack", "subscriptionPeriodNumberIOS": "0", "subscriptionPeriodUnitIOS": "DAY", "title": "", "type": "Do not use this. It returned sub only before"}]
```

The result on Physical handset(iPhone 7Plus running IOS14):

```
Checking Products [{"countryCode": "USA", "currency": "USD", "description": "", "discounts": [], "introductoryPrice": "", "introductoryPriceAsAmountIOS": "", "introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriodsIOS": "", "introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS": "", "introductoryPriceSubscriptionPeriodIOS": "", "localizedPrice": "$0.99", "price": "0.99", "productId": "DokoMonthlyPack", "subscriptionPeriodNumberIOS": "0", "subscriptionPeriodUnitIOS": "DAY", "title": "", "type": "Do not use this. It returned sub only before"}]
```

The same result I am getting on the different physical devices I have tried in India. Please help me get the result in INR.

Thanks in Advance Sir/Madam.